# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/UserTransaction

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jndi

While deploying my application on weblogic 12 I am facing following exception

> weblogic.application.ModuleException:
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up
>   comp/env/UserTransaction in /app/webapp/Demo-UNCONTROLLED
>   ARTIFACT.war/895045661.; remaining name 'comp/env/UserTransaction'

My spring-jpa.xml is as follows

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="userTransaction" jndi-name="java:comp/env/UserTransaction" resource-ref="true" cache="true"/>
```

context.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/private/tool" sessionCookieName="JSESSIONID_TOOL" disableURLRewriting="true">
    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction" factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
</Context>
```

How to configure UserTransaction in weblogic? Why my application is failing to lookup **comp/env/UserTransaction** ?